# Why won't python load this file despite it existing in the directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to load and store a wide range of transcribed conversations into python. The naming convention for the conversations is as follows:

```
"convo (1)", "convo (2)", etc.
```

initially I loaded the files like this:

```
convo33 = load("IntakeCalls/convo (33).txt")
convos.append(convo33)
```

and this worked. However, there are too many calls to manually enter them in this way so I wrote this block of code.

```
for i in range(1, 153):
  temp = load(r"IntakeCalls/convo ({})".format(i))
  convos.append(temp)
```

However, I keep receiving this error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'IntakeCalls/convo (1)'
```

Despite the same file working previously in the other method. Is this a problem with the string encoding because of the `.format()`? If so how can I fix it and/or how can I do this in a more efficient manner. I even tried changing the code to this, with no luck:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)

for i in range(1, 153):
    temp = load(os.path.join("IntakeCalls/convo ({})".format(i)))
    convos.append(temp)
```

Comment: you're missing a file extension in the _new_ method. `'IntakeCalls/convo (1)' != 'IntakeCalls/convo (1).txt'`

Comment: maybe you are missing the '.txt'  should be load(r"IntakeCalls/convo ({}).txt".format(i))

Comment: @reportgunner wow what a silly mistake! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I was just missing the ".txt" file extension in my new block of code! Thanks for the help!